Error: "FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command."

FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run
a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android fbconnection (android) --package-name=fbconnection --json --project=fir-connection-961a6
ERROR: Failed to create Android app for project fir-connection-961a6. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

This is the error.
I don't know how to solve this.
